# Finding the point at which a function is continuous

Tags: functions, continuity

I am trying to understand the solution to the following question.

At which $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if $x$ is rational,}\\1-x&\text{if $x$ is irrational,}\end{cases}$$ continuous?

The solution states that the only answer is $c=1/2$, but am not sure why this is so.

I have thought about what might happen if we suppose (for a contradiction) that $f$ is continuous at some $c\neq1/2$.  To arrive at a contradiction, I am trying to use the fact that $\exists$ an irrational number between any two numbers.  However, I have not yet managed to arrive at a contradiction.

Could I have some suggestions as to how to progress, please?

Answer (score 1):

For my feeling the whole question is a bit hypothetical. It helps understanding the distribution of rational and irrational numbers and the definition of continuous functions, though.

Per definition, for a continuous function $f(x)$, you can provide a $\delta$ for any given $\varepsilon$, so that $f(x-d)-f(x)<\varepsilon$ for all $d \in [-\delta...\delta]$. More simple, you can add little random deviations to $x$ and you will only get litte random deviations in $f(x)$.

The problem with this function definition is: For any given $\delta$, even the smallest, you will find both rational and irrational numbers between $x$ and $x+\delta$. So, for any $\varepsilon$ smaller $|(x) - (1-x)|$, no $\delta$ can be found to fulfill the requirement.

The requirement for continuous functions can only be satisfied where $x$ and $1-x$ converge. As both are linear functions, they converge only once.

Comment: @ philipp Why have you written 'for any $\epsilon$ smaller $|(x)-(1-x)|$?  I would have thought that this should read 'for any $\epsilon$ smaller than $|(x)-(1-c)|\ldots$', where $c\in[-\delta, \delta]$.  Please could you explain?

Comment: $x$ and $1-x$ are the two definitions of $f(x)$, so $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|$, where $x_1$ is rational and $x_2$ irrational, but both are virtually the same, is $|x-(1-x)|$

Comment: @ philipp  By 'both are virtually the same', do you mean that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are almost equal to each other?

Answer (score 0):

This is because at $x = \frac{1}{2}$ we have $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} = 1 - x$

Comment: Alright.  However, how do we know whether or not $f$ is continuous at some other point $c\neq1/2$?

Comment: Think of it this way: We know that the real numbers are dense, with the rationals being countably infinite on any interval, and the irrationals being uncountably infinite. At $\frac{1}{2}$, there are an infinitely dense amount of $x$ with corresponding images $1-x$ in the neighborhood of $f(\frac{1}{2})$. When we aren't at $\frac{1}{2}$, we have an infinite dense interval of points mapping onto $1-x$, and a countable set of points mapping onto $x$, therefore not continuos.

Comment: @CKKOY Suppose that your function is continuous at some $c$. Then:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\substack{r\rightarrow c \\ r\in \Bbb Q}} f(r) & = \lim_{\substack{x\rightarrow c \\ x\in \Bbb R -\Bbb Q}} f(x) &= f(c)\\
\lim_{\substack{r\rightarrow c \\ r\in \Bbb Q}} r &= \lim_{\substack{x\rightarrow c \\ x\in \Bbb R -\Bbb Q}} 1-x & \\
c &= 1-c
\end{align}$$

So $c=1/2$

Comment: @Farnight This was a very helpful response.